# After page refresh on selected option call function

Tags: jquery

I have one option box on change event if I change the option after that it's execute some code and function it's work good.

My problem is that if I refresh the page the value which I have selected before refresh page is also selected after refresh that page but I am not able run the code after refresh page or without change the option.

I am expecting the answer when I refresh the page I want run that function and code each time without change the option after refresh the page.

```
jQuery('#input_29_32').on('change', function(e){
    //running some code and function
    alert("example");
    employer();
});
```

Comment: Store the selected value in localStorge or cookie the read it on page load

Comment: I believe he is saying that the correct option is selected but what is displayed is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Store the selected value in `localStorge` or `cookie` the read it on page load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#input_29_32').on('change', function(e) {
        //Store value
        localStorage.setItem('inputValue', this.value);
        //Rest of your code
    });

    //If data exists
    if (localStorage.getItem('inputValue')) {
        jQuery('#input_29_32')
            .val(localStorage.getItem('inputValue')) //set value
            .trigger('change'); //trigger change event
    }
});
```

Comment: hi satpal when i add if block in my js file form is not displaying

Comment: @SanjayNakate, Are you getting any error in your page?

Comment: i did not got any error but i have solved my problem in different way i appreciate answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Just run your code on document ready.

```
jQuery(function () {
    alert("example");
    employer();

    jQuery('#input_29_32').on('change', function(e){
        alert("example");
        employer();
    });
});
```

Comment: but i wanted to run the function on change option also and if i change the option and then refresh the page

Comment: @SanjayNakate I have edited my answer, this will now run when the page is loaded or refreshed or when changed. If you wish to persist the selection the Satpal's answer is the correct one.

Comment: so i need to run function two time i did this something like that jQuery(function () {
    alert("example");
    employer();  jQuery('#input_29_32').on('change', function(e){
        alert("example");
        employer();
    });
}); it will run the funtion ervery page refresh??

Answer (score 0):

just put the same code in

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // grab the selected value from option and fire your function
        alert('example');
        employer();
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for stealing my answer and badly formatting it :)

Comment: sorry to put this but i dint saw your answer before putting this.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is as follows:

```
function itemChanged() {

// you might want to check here that item has actually changed here... 
   alert("example");
    employer();
}

$('#input_29_32').on('change',itemChanged);
```

And on document load also call the same itemChanged event.

```
$(function(){
   itemChanged();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same code to run on page refresh also you can put the same code in *document ready event* along with on change event.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert("example");
    employer();
});
```

Comment: It seems all of us were solving together and hit the submit, and then we see there are already 5 of them !!! :)